# How to use Quarter-circle contour?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

So I want to know how to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$for integrable $f(x)$ using the quarter circle contour, assuming that $f(x)$ has no singularities that aren't poles in that region. So, I know that by using residue theorem $$\int_C f(x)dx=2\pi i\sum_k\text{Res}(f,z_k)$$Where $z_k$ is a pole of $f$. So is the following true $$\int_C f(x)dx=\Re\left(\int_0^Rf(z)dz+\int_0^{Ri}f(z)dz+\int_\Gamma\right)$$(Where $\Gamma$ is the arc)? I don't really understand how to use the quarter circle contour to evaluate integrals. So is my thinking right? If not, how am I supposed to use this contour? As a note, I got $Ri$ since there is a radius point upward from $0$ to $Ri$.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting $\Re$ from, but if you are traveling counterclockwise on that contour, then your equation should be $\int_{C} f(z)dz = \int_0^R f(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{Ri}^0 f(z)dz$, assuming the integrals converge as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: I want the real part since we are originally calculating a real integral. But why do you switch the bounds of only the second integral?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but the closest example I can think of is evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}\ln\left(1+x^{4}\right)}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}dx$. However, if you let $f(z)$ equal the integrand, you must deal with a branch cut and a pole on the imaginary axis. It's possible to evaluate the integral using [this contour](https://imgur.com/a/8yJPQ5P), but it's just a lot of work.

Comment: I switched the bounds because when you finish traveling counterclockwise on $\Gamma$, you start at the point $(0, iR)$ and end at the point $(0,0)$. (EDIT) If you want the real part of the integral, you must apply the real part to the other side as well.